# D3JS Force network: Links to nodes that are grouped using formula in transform fnt

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am applying a formula to cluster nodes in D3js force network graph. I do not know how to get my links to attach to the new, clustered node locations.

For the nodes I changed my original code from:

```
force.on("tick", function() {
      node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
```

To code that clusters the nodes by their category (nodeCategory):

```
node.attr("transform", function(d) {
  var xm = d.x + intensity*Math.cos(angle*nodeGroup(d.nodeCategory));
  var ym = d.y + intensity*Math.sin(angle*nodeGroup(d.nodeCategory));
  return "translate(" + xm + "," + ym + ")";
});
```

The nodes now cluster successfully based on their category in the data. However, I do not know how to update the code for the links (edges). The links are no longer attached to the nodes and reflect the non-clustered node locations:

```
edges.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
     .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
     .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
     .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
```

How do I apply the transformation to the links?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NovasTaylor/rj11L1ye/) that illustrates the problem.

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the links are in the wrong place because the nodes are displaced from their (d.x,d.y) positions by the grouping transform.  So `d.source.x` and `d.source.y` are not the position you want for the link.

You need to *update d.x and d.y to reflect the true position of the node* so that the links are where you want.

The usual way to do this would be something like...

```
force.on("tick", function(e) {

    node.attr("transform", function(d) {
      d.x += (intensity*Math.cos(angle*nodeGroup(d.nodeCategory)) - d.x)*e.alpha;
      d.y += (intensity*Math.sin(angle*nodeGroup(d.nodeCategory)) - d.y)*e.alpha;
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });
    edges.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
         .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
         .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
         .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
}
```

The idea is to have a position regulator with varying gain that is a function of the force alpha. That way the speed at which the nodes are moved at decays with time.

Here it is in context...

```js
//Width and height for SVG area
    var w = 500;
    var h = 200;

    // nb_group, angle, intensity: Used in clustering the nodes  
    var nb_group=4;
    var angle = 2*Math.PI/nb_group;
    var intensity = 100;
    
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
              .attr("width", w)
              .attr("height", h)

    var colors = d3.scale.category10()
              .range(["#FFFF00",  //YELLOW
                      "#377eb8",  //BLUE
                      "#4daf4a",  //GREEN
                      "#e41a1c",  //RED
                      ]);  
    var dataset = {
        "nodes":[
            {"id":0,"name":"A","nodeCategory":"1"},
            {"id":1,"name":"AA","nodeCategory":"1"},
            {"id":2,"name":"B","nodeCategory":"2"},
            {"id":3,"name":"BB","nodeCategory":"2"},
            {"id":4,"name":"C","nodeCategory":"3"},
            {"id":5,"name":"CC","nodeCategory":"3"},
            {"id":6,"name":"D","nodeCategory":"4"},
            {"id":7,"name":"DD","nodeCategory":"4"},
            {"id":8,"name":"DDD","nodeCategory":"4"}
        ],
        "edges":[
            {"source":0,"target":2,"value":""},
            {"source":1,"target":3,"value":""},
            {"source":2,"target":4,"value":""},
            {"source":3,"target":5,"value":""},
            {"source":4,"target":6,"value":""},
            {"source":5,"target":7,"value":""},
            {"source":6,"target":8,"value":""},
            {"source":7,"target":0,"value":""},
            {"source":8,"target":1,"value":""}
       ]
    }
    var force = d3.layout.force()
                  .nodes(dataset.nodes)
                  .links(dataset.edges)
                  .gravity(.5)
                  .charge(-100)
                  .linkDistance(10)
                  .size([w, h])
                  .start();
    var drag = force.drag()
                    .on("dragstart", dragstart);
    var edges = svg.selectAll("line")
                 .data(dataset.edges)
                 .enter()
                 .append("line")
                  .style("stroke", "black");
    var nodes = svg.selectAll("g.node")
                 .data(dataset.nodes)
                 .enter()
                 .append("g")
                 .on("dblclick", dblclick)
                 .call(drag);
    nodes.append("circle")
         .attr("r", 10)
         .style("fill", function(d) { return colors(d.nodeCategory); })
         .style("stroke", "black") 
         // Mousover Node - highlight node by fading the node colour during mouseover
         .on('mouseover', function(d){
            var nodeSelection = d3.select(this).style({opacity:'0.5'});
         })
         //Mouseout Node  - bring node back to full colour   
         .on('mouseout', function(d){
             var nodeSelection= d3.select(this).style({opacity:'1.0',}) 
         })
    // dx sets how close to the node the label appears
    nodes.append("text")
         .attr("class", "nodetext")
         .attr("dx", 12)
         .attr("dy", ".35em")
         .text(function(d) { return d.name });            // Just the name
    // Edge Paths
    var edgepaths = svg.selectAll(".edgepath")
                       .data(dataset.edges)
                       .enter()
                       .append('path')
                       .attr({'d': function(d) {return 'M '+d.source.x+' '+d.source.y+' L '+ d.target.x +' '+d.target.y},
                           'id':function(d,i) {return 'edgepath'+i}})
                       .style("pointer-events", "none");

    force.on("tick", function(e) {
        // position regulator for nodes must update d.x and d.y BEFORE links are positioned
        nodes.attr("transform", function(d) {
              d.x += (intensity*Math.cos(angle*(d.nodeCategory)) + w/2 - d.x)*e.alpha;
              d.y += (intensity*Math.sin(angle*(d.nodeCategory)) + h/2 - d.y)*e.alpha;
              return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        });

        edges.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
            .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
            .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
            .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
        // ORIGINAL transform for Nodes:  
        // nodes.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
        // New Transform for nodes:
        // PROBLEM HERE   
        edgepaths.attr('d', function(d) { var path='M '+d.source.x+' '+d.source.y+' L '+ d.target.x +' '+d.target.y;
                                            //console.log(d)
                                            return path});       
    });     
    
    // Double click to 'unfix' the node and have forces start to act on it again.
    function dblclick(d) {
      d3.select(this).classed("fixed", d.fixed = false);
    }
    // Set the "fixed" property of the dragged node to TRUE when a dragstart event is initiated,
    //   - removes "forces" from acting on that node and changing its position.
    function dragstart(d) {
      d3.select(this).classed("fixed", d.fixed = true);
    }
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
svg { outline: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Cool Blue.  The speed and decay are working fine in my graph. My problem is that after I switch to clustering the nodes based on adding the formula (code block #2), the edges (lines) are no longer attached to the nodes.  The line position x1,y1 for source and x2,y2 for target locations no longer correspond to the node locations. The edges appear on the graph but are all at the wrong locations because I have transformed the node points but not the start and end of each line that connects two nodes.  I hope that is clearer.  - T

Comment: Cool Blue : Still having trouble getting your code to work for me. I added a JSFiddle to my original post. I'd appreciate it very much if someone would try altering that code to show me how to change the code for the edges (links/lines) in that example.

Comment: OK, I'll take a look... do you get the basic point of my suggestions?

Comment: Yes!  Now I get it. Thank you very much for taking the time to adjust my code and show the functional example.  This helped my understanding very much and I will be applying this in several future graphs so I really appreciate your effort.

Comment: My original answer was full of typos so sorry about that. I could have added the w/2,h/2 offset in the tick function instead of using the transform and maybe you should do it that way... I updated the snippet to be like that.